# option recompile faster when using local variables

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

We have a partitioned table([AdvertisementUnits]) in Azure that we are running queries against.
Regularly we are running into problems with the QO not using covering indexes.

Example:

```
declare @__param_0 datetimeoffset(7) = '2019-06-24'
declare @__param_1 datetimeoffset(7) = '2019-06-25'
declare @__p_3 int = '0'
declare @__p_4 int = '1000'
SELECT [a].[Id],[a].[Created],  [a].[EarliestStart], etc...
FROM [AdvertisementUnits] AS [a]
WHERE ( ([a].[EarliestStart] >= @__param_0) AND ([a].[EarliestStart] < @__param_1))
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
OFFSET  @__p_3 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_4 ROWS ONLY
```

There exists a covering query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AdvertisementUnits_EarliestStart_FullInclude] ON [dbo].[AdvertisementUnits]
(
    [EarliestStart] DESC
)
INCLUDE([a].[Created],  [a].[EarliestStart], etc...)
```

If I run this query it takes around 3m. If I use a query hint for the covering index, it's less than 3s.

[slow query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkpalUM0L)

[super fast query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkKG-IzCI)

What I have done:

- "UPDATE STATISTICS AdvertisementUnits WITH FULLSCAN, ALL" -> no improvement
- "ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE ;" -> no improvement
- Added "option (recompile)" -> index is used
- Removed OFFSET -> index is used
- ORDER BY a.EarliestStart -> index is used

What really irritates me is that without option recompile the QO refuses to use the index even after updating the statistics and emptying the query cache.

I can not use option recompile here because we use EF Core and injecting it for one specific query is pretty impractical.

Edit: to add to the confusion...

If I use literal values instead of variables, the fast query plan is generated every time:

```
SELECT [a].[Id],[a].[Created],  [a].[EarliestStart]
FROM [AdvertisementUnits] AS [a]
WHERE ([a].[EarliestStart] >=  '2019-06-14') AND ([a].[EarliestStart] < '2019-06-15')
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Hi @TT. great idea. Done.

Comment: this is mainly a row goal issue. It does not know how selective your `WHERE ( ([a].[EarliestStart] >= @__param_0) AND ([a].[EarliestStart] < @__param_1))` predicate is going to be in this case as you are using variables and assumes it will only have to do 600 lookups before it finds the first 1,000 rows that match (though it estimates you only want 100 also as it doesn't sniff that either). In reality you get 23,733,840 lookups - but I assume in reality you are using parameters not variables so the behaviour there will be different again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the responses I found the part of the documentation that explains why queries with local variables perform better when executed with "option (recompile)".

From the [official documentation for recompile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15):

> But in addition to using the procedure's current parameter values, the RECOMPILE query hint also uses the values of any local variables inside the stored procedure when you compile the statement.

That seems to be the difference to normal execution where local variables are ignored.

[Ed Pollack on sqlshack.com](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)

> Because the value of local variables is not known until runtime, the query optimizer needs to make a very rough estimate of row counts prior to execution.

This would explain the observed behaviour.

Only solution to solve this:

- literal values(not a good option)
- stored procedures
- use 'option (recompile)'

If you use EF Core, the only option is injecting the recompile for certain slow queries

My personal problem:

I took slow queries from "Azure Performance Insight" and used local variables to test them. Because of the "feature" described above this resulted in a different query plan than expected. EF Core uses a "parameterized query". Which performs like a stored procedure. So in the end the covering index was actually used on prod the whole time, just not by my local bad query.

Additional sources:

[Jes Schultz - Parameter Sniffing in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Something%20Smells%20Funny&text=SQL%20Server%20uses%20a%20process,to%20create%20an%20execution%20plan.)

[Gail Shaw - How to Confuse the SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)

Comment: There's a whole universe of reasons behind the all too common "it runs bad on Production but fine on my laptop" issues. (You hit the reverse situation, but still.)

Comment: This helped me on the right track with my EF Core query. I tried `EXEC sp_updatestats;` and then ran my query with my slow-performing parameters, and that didn't help. `option (recompile)` did. This hint helped:

"EF Core uses a "parameterized query". Which performs like a stored procedure"

So I ran `sp_updatestats` again and then immediately ran my query with more typical (but still slow) parameters, and that seemed to do the trick. 

My next step would have been to inject `option (recompile)` via EF extension function, as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/1664556

Answer (score 1):

I'm still rough on the subject, but I *think* what's going on is something like:

- The query optimizer looks at the query, sees there are from/through variables to apply to column `EarliestStart`, checks the stats on the column, does NOT "sniff" the variables (this is not a stored procedure) and, not knowing anything about them, figures reading the whole table is the safest thing to do so as to avoid excessive bookmark lookups.
- When WITH (RECOMPILE) is included, it presumably does consider the actual values being used *this* time, realizes (via the table statistics) that the index scan + bookmark lookups beats the table scan, and proceeds accordingly.

(Sorry, I don't know why the lack of ORDER BY and OFFSET commands produce a better query. Hands-on messing around would produce more info on this.)

If you can somehow wire the query WITH RECOMPILE, that would seem to be the way to go--you get a hit on query compilation, but it's a trivial query and shouldn't take that much time, and overall it's superior to continuous table scans.

Comment: Thank you. The first bullet point got me on the right track.