# EF Core takes a lot of time, sometimes, to perform SELECT query

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, entity-framework-core, locking

I am using EF Core 6 vs a SQL Server DB.
Sometimes, the execution of a SELECT query takes more than 30 seconds, and goes in timeout.

If I execute the very same SQL generated by EF Core (with the very same parameters, on the same DB, just a few seconds after the timeout), it takes less than a second.

During the overall period, the DB server stays with CPU < 30%.

Running the SQL query on SQL Server Management Studio, I can see that the execution plan is ideal (i.e. it uses the indexes, etc.).

So I am afraid there could be some locking that stops the DB from returning the result of the query.

Is there a way to specify to EF Core e.g. the ISOLATION LEVEL of the query, or even some concurrency / locking strategy?

In my specific scenario, it's ok to have dirty or not completely up-to-date reads, because we have procedures in place to retrieve the clean data in a subsequent round of queries.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into parameter sniffing issues. If your parameter types aren't matching the target schema, the conversion could be causing significant latency on the initial call during query plan generation.

Comment: Have you set the READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT option on your database?  With that SELECT doesn't need any locks on the data.

Comment: thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, pardon my ignorance, how can I set "READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT" on the DB? Is it a setting of the DB itself or of the caller, e.g. EF Core?

Comment: With the ALTER DATABASE command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16 or in the SSMS Database Property page.

Comment: I implemented both the accepted answer approach and yours, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not new question when SQL Server may slowdown queries because of [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/). Problem can be solved by converting parameters to constants or by adding [OPTION(RECOMPILE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver16#recompile) to the end of the query. This answer adds `DbCommandInterceptor` to `DbContextOptions` and appends `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint to particular queries.

**Configuring DbContext**

```cs
builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .UseRecompileExtensions(); // registering interceptor
```

**How to use in queries:**

```cs
var name = "SomeName";
var result = context.SomeItems
    .Where(x => x.Name == name)
    .WithRecompile() // it marks query as a query which needs RECOMPILE query hint
    .ToList();
```

Then to SQL Server will be sent the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[Name]
FROM [SomeItems] AS [s]
WHERE [s].[Name] = @__name_0
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

**And implementation of extensions:**

I have put everything into one static class for simplifying answer. Tested on EF Core 6, but should work for lower versions also.

```cs
public static class RecompileExtensions
{
    private const string RecompileTag = "recompile_query_tag";
    private const string RecompileComment = "-- " + RecompileTag + "\r\n";

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseRecompileExtensions(this DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.AddInterceptors(RecompileInterceptor.Instance);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WithRecompile<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.TagWith(RecompileTag);
    }

    private class RecompileInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public static RecompileInterceptor Instance = new();

        public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            CorrectCommand(command);

            return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
        {
            CorrectCommand(command);

            return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
        }

        private static void CorrectCommand(DbCommand command)
        {
            var newQuery = command.CommandText.Replace(RecompileComment, "");

            // if query was changed, we have to append RECOMPILE option
            if (!ReferenceEquals(newQuery, command.CommandText))
            {
                // remove rest of the comment
                if (newQuery.StartsWith("\r\n"))
                    newQuery = newQuery.Substring(2);

                newQuery += "\r\nOPTION(RECOMPILE)";
                command.CommandText = newQuery;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Starting from SQL Server 2016 it is possible to disable Parameter Sniffing via [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```cs
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = OFF;
```

Comment: Recompiling every query execution is a dangerous solution. If you know which parameter gives you an optimal plan, you can use `OPTIMIZE FOR` instead of recompile.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, with EF Core you have not too much choices. I saw similar problems earlier and questioner was decided to transfer every parameter into constant - which is more complicated solution.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts the ".WithRecompile()" on the query should handle that, or am I missing something? It should not run on every query in the application, just when ".WithRecompile()" is used?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts How exactly would you do that in EF core?

Comment: You can't use OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR()) with EF. Since the parameter names are generated by entity framework.  If this is truly an issue, you can retrieve data with Dapper, so you have full control of the query statement.

Comment: Nice extension! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Recompile is not recommended, it may harm the good running application.
For large-scale data , I personally recommended using DBQuery or Simple ADO.net