# EF Core 6 - Implement and intercept ReaderExecutingAsync in a DbCommandInterceptor

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I implemented a DbCommandInterceptor like **Svyatoslav** answered in this question:

[EF Core takes a lot of time, sometimes, to perform SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073436/ef-core-takes-a-lot-of-time-sometimes-to-perform-select-query)

But I'm unable to intercept the **ReaderExecutingAsync** method, when I call a ToListAsync() method in my LINQ query.

```
// the ReaderExecutingAsync method is not intercepted
var result = await context.Users
    .WithRecompile()
    .ToListAsync();
```

The **ReaderExecuting** method fires correctly, when I call a ToList() sync.

```
// the ReaderExecuting method is intercepted
var result = await context.Users
    .WithRecompile()
    .ToList();
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you are suffering from parameter sniffing if that is the full query. Parameter sniffing can only occur when you pass in parameters to a query. And the sample code is not showing this.  So I'm guess you are facing locking/blocking issues.

Comment: While your query do not need interception because of lack of parameters, have you registered interceptor with `UseRecompileExtensions` call? Also which EF Core version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your message. I simplified the query just for example, the concerned query is more complex, integrating also pagination and ordering.

Comment: Yes, I registered the interceptor correctly, I'm able to intercept the ReaderExecuting method, but not the ReaderExecutingAsync.

            `services.AddDbContext<Subscribers.SubscribersDbContext>((options) =>
            {
                options
                    .UseSqlServer(appSettings.ConnectionString)
                    .UseRecompileExtensions();
            });`

Comment: Tried with EF Core 6.0.1 and 6.0.8.

Comment: Strange, just tested, works for EF Core 6.0.8. Both `async` and `non-async` calls are successfully intercepted. Do you have any third-party libraries which extends EF Core?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you give me a boost with your last reply. I noticed the referenced assembly "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" (with the `DbCommandInterceptor` class) **was 3.x and no 6.0.8**, but no nuget library was referenced for it. 

So, I installed the 6.0.8 version and now it works like a charm!