# Using Tagging with Entity Framework Add or Atach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Based on the following example from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors you can use tagging to intercept a query like the following

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs.TagWith("Use hint: robust plan").ToList();
```

and then create an intercepter to identify query you want to modify based on tag/comment

```
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ManipulateCommand(command);

        return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
    }

    private static void ManipulateCommand(DbCommand command)
    {
        if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("-- Use hint: robust plan", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            command.CommandText += " OPTION (ROBUST PLAN)";
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatly DbSet such as
**Add**, and **Attach** does not have an extension to do Tagging,

Is there a way you can use something similar or anything related, in order to identify a specific **insert** command in the Interception.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. Probably you can intercept command which inserts, but without query tagging. SaveChanges do not use Query hints. Opposite question, why `OPTION (ROBUST PLAN)`?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv
OPTION (ROBUST PLAN)---that just microsoft example.

Comment: So, what you are trying to achieve? Do you have any problems with queries? Usually with EF users have Parameters Sniffing problem, which is already answered by me  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  when I use Attach or Add I want to add some extra property or parameter, using which I can interesct query and Identify that the query has that property and update it. The problem Add and Attach does not uses this IQueryable<T>