# LINQ to SQL nullable boolean without .Value caused TimeoutException

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have below Customer Entity Class with (other properties went off for clarity):

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I make an HTTP GET request with query param to give me all not Deleted Customers (query params are wrapped in `CustomerFilter`  object). IsDeleted Prop of that filter object is nullable.

```
public class CustomerFilter
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**GET api/Customers?Name=TestCustomer&isDeleted=false**

```
var response = await _customerService.Get(new CustomerFilter{Name=name, IsDeleted=isDeleted})
```

in my repository i have following code:

```
public async Task<List<Customers>> Get(CustomerFilter customerFilter)
    {
        var customersQuerable= _context.Customers.AsQueryable();

        if (customersFilter.Name!= null)
        {
            customersQuerable= customersQuerable.Where(_ => _.Name.Contains(customerFilter.Name.RemoveEmpty()));
        }

  
        if (customersFilter.IsDeleted!= null)
        {
            customersQuerable= customersQuerable.Where(_ => _.IsDeleted== customerFilter.IsDeleted);
        }

        return await customersQuerable.Skip(customersFilter.Offset).Take(customersFilter.Limit).ToListAsync();

   }
```

When IsDeleted Property is true it works fine but when it is false there is SQL Timeout Exception.

After several attempts I found out that problem is in IsDeleted nullable property. When i put `.Value`:

```
if (customersFilter.IsDeleted!= null)
    {
        customersQuerable= customersQuerable.Where(_ => _.IsDeleted== customerFilter.IsDeleted.Value);
    }
```

I was successfull in recieving result.

Question: Why false value caused the issue even though I never passed `null` as filter property for IsDeleted. The value was always true or false. If it was some LINQ to SQL translation with nullable values i guess it should also not work with true value.

true worked, false caused SQL TimeoutException and when I changed the code with **.Value** on nullable bool while constructing queryable in where expression it is working fine.

**EDIT**

I have extracted queries generated by both cases with and without `.Value` and both queries when executed directly in database returned result instantly. Execution plans are the same.

Comment: That's not LINQ to SQL. That was a completely different ORM that was released before Entity Framework.

Comment: As for the question itself, you'll have to explain which EF Core version is used and provide actual executable code, not just snippets. You don't need and actually *shouldn't* use `_` as the name of your entity in expressions. `_` here is an actual parameter name. In other cases though it means you want to discard parameter. You don't need to use `.Value` with nullable properties. You'll have to check the generated SQL to see why there was a timeout. Perhaps the generated query is `where (c.IsDeleted IS NULL and @isDeleted IS NULL) or (c.IsDeleted=@isDeleted)` ?

Comment: In any case, both queries will result in a full table scan and probably timeouts, because neither can use indexes. `bit` columns can't be indexed. And `Name.Contains(someParam)` translates to `NAME LIKE '%' + @someParam + '%'` which can't use any indexes. If the condition was `StartsWith` you'd get `NAME LIKE @someParam +'%'` which is equivalent to a range query and *can* use indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EntityFramework version is: EntityFramework.Core 6.0.5. 

When i take generated query and execute it directly in SSMS it works fine in all cases the problem is only in code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and part of generated query

DECLARE @__customerFilter_IsDeleted_1 bit = CAST(1 AS bit);

...

WHERE  ([c].[IsDeleted] = @__customerFilter_IsDeleted_1)

Comment: @bartkub89 And this is the `WHERE` clause in SQL in both cases (with or w/o `.Value` inside LINQ query expression)? In other words, 2 absolutely equal SQL queries? Sorry, but it's really hard to believe.

Comment: @bartkub89 Even though I checked it and they (SQL queries) really seem to be one the same, just the name of the parameter is different. Hmm, makes no any sense. Does it happen always, e.g. the query w/o `.Value` fails, and with `.Value` succeeds?

Comment: How many records returns case without deleted records?

Comment: @IvanStoev every time when i make a request where there is no .Value on **isDeleted** it fails with timeout. When i add .Value it is a success. it happens every time.

i made a `customersQuerable.ToQuetyString()` in both cases with and without .Value and queries are equal are the same (checked 4 times). It is hard to believe for me as well and i cannot find answer for that.  Maybe some bug with entity framework? 

@SvyatoslavDanyliv isDeleted=false --> 69 thousand records  isDeleted= true ---> 8 records

Comment: What is the point to select 69 thousand records? For sure it is slow.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv there might be plenty of business reasons for example to create a report. In my case that is business reason. 69k rows is not a lot for database. Direct query on DB takes 5 seconds. Besides there is **Skip** and **Take** operators so the query supports pagination.

Comment: So even if I use paginated result `Skip(10).Take(10)` the issue still exists .

Comment: I would suggest to examine generated SQL and execution plan. If there is no sorting, Take(10) should process immediately.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv executions plans are exactly the same and as i sad when i execute generated query directly in Database, results are immediately returned in both generated queries with and without .Value prop

Comment: Could you please try this [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316) and let me know?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It worked with this extension! What is the issue then?

Comment: Then upvote my extension ;) In description I have explained that this is Parameter Sniffing, when SQL Server choses bad execution plan for particular parameters. In SQL Server Management Studio you have not used parameters, but variables - not reproducible.

Comment: I can make answer how to avoid this in your case, without extension.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv please create an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Probably SQL Server cached bad execution plan for parameter `@__customerFilter_IsDeleted_1`. It is called [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/).
Removing parameter usage should help in speedup query:

```cs
if (customersFilter.IsDeleted != null)
{
    if (customerFilter.IsDeleted.Value)
        customersQuerable = customersQuerable.Where(x => x.IsDeleted);
    else
        customersQuerable = customersQuerable.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
}
```

It is easy if you have just `Boolean` parameters, but if there is `Integer` parameter, we cannot easily create workaround. For such purpose I have created extension [WithRecompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316), which add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the end of the SQL query. For such queries SQL Server do not cache execution plan.