# Fulltext search 10 times slower than created SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

**Summary:**

- Test data with 10k projects, 5 comments per project, 100k chars unique text per comment
- Entity Framework Core runs the query up to 10 times slower compared to native SQL
- The columns for fulltext search are of type string
- I don't use lazy loading
- Tried different approaches for the fulltext columns
- The speed is sometimes 10 times faster
- I always waited until the fulltext index was completed (status 0)

I run a semi complex query to perform a fulltext search with entity framework core (7.0.5) on my database:

`BaseEntity` model:

```cs
public class BaseEntity
{
    // Main data
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string SearchKeywords { get; set; }

    // Audit data
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

`Project` model class:

```cs
[Table("Projects")]
public class Project : BaseEntity
{
    // Main data
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProjectLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProjectStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProjectEnd { get; set; }
    //...

    // Computed columns (see ApplicationDbContext)
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string MainProperty { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string FullText { get; set; }

    // Foreign data
    [ForeignKey("ProjectStatusId")]
    public virtual DropDown ProjectStatus { get; set; }
    public string ProjectStatusId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerContactId")]
    public virtual CustomerContact CustomerContact { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContactId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountOwnerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser AccountOwner { get; set; }
    public string AccountOwnerId { get; set; }

    // Foreign data collections
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UploadedFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProjectCandidate> ProjectCandidates { get; set; }
}
```

`OnModelCreating`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // ...
    builder.Entity<Project>().Property(p => p.FullText).HasComputedColumnSql("CONCAT([SearchKeywords], ' ', [ProjectName], ' ', [ProjectDescription], ' ', [ProjectLocation])");
    // ...
}
```

`GetProjects` method:

```cs
private void GetProjects(ApplicationDbContext context, string FullTextFilter)
{
    var projects = context.Projects.Where(x => x.TeamId == "85216daa-a05f-4c0a-92c4-0920f8349370").AsNoTracking();

    projects = projects.Where(x =>
         EF.Functions.Contains(x.FullText, FullTextFilter) ||
         EF.Functions.Contains(x.Customer.FullText, FullTextFilter) ||
         EF.Functions.Contains(x.CustomerContact.FullText, FullTextFilter) ||
         EF.Functions.Contains(x.AccountOwner.FullText, FullTextFilter) ||
         x.UploadedFiles.Any(c => EF.Functions.Contains(c.FullText, FullTextFilter)) ||
         x.Comments.Any(c => EF.Functions.Contains(c.FullText, FullTextFilter))
         );

    projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.ProjectName);

    projects = projects.Skip(0);
    projects = projects.Take(20);

    var projectsDto = projects.Select(x => new ProjectOverviewDto
    {
         Id = x.Id,
         ProjectName = x.ProjectName,
         ProjectDescription = x.ProjectDescription,
         ProjectLocation = x.ProjectLocation,
         
         ProjectStatus = new DropDownMinimalDto { Name = x.ProjectStatus.Name },
         Customer = new CustomerMinimalDto { CompanyName = x.Customer.CompanyName },
         CustomerContact = new CustomerContactMinimalDto { LastName = x.CustomerContact.LastName },
         AccountOwner = new ApplicationUserMinimalDto { LastName = x.AccountOwner.LastName }
    });

    var projectsList = projectsDto.ToList();
}
```

I run this function like this (test only):

```cs
GetProjects(context, "\"*def*\"");
```

The execution time varies a lot, I already got some "lucky" moments with about 500 ms, but the most of the time it needs **10,000** ms. Some of my other tests takes up to **20,000** ms.

The generated SQL looks like this (seen in SQL Server Profiler):

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[ProjectName], [t].[ProjectDescription], [t].[ProjectLocation], [d].[Name], [t].[CompanyName], [t].[LastName], [t].[LastName0] AS [LastName]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[ProjectDescription], [p].[ProjectLocation], [p].[ProjectName], [p].[ProjectStatusId], [c].[CompanyName], [c0].[LastName], [a].[LastName] AS [LastName0]
    FROM [Projects] AS [p]
    LEFT JOIN [Customers] AS [c] ON [p].[CustomerId] = [c].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [CustomerContacts] AS [c0] ON [p].[CustomerContactId] = [c0].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [p].[AccountOwnerId] = [a].[Id]
    WHERE [p].[TeamId] = N''85216daa-a05f-4c0a-92c4-0920f8349370'' AND (CONTAINS([p].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1) OR CONTAINS([c].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1) OR CONTAINS([c0].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1) OR CONTAINS([a].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1) OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [UploadedFiles] AS [u]
        WHERE [p].[Id] = [u].[ProjectId] AND CONTAINS([u].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1)) OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Comments] AS [c1]
        WHERE [p].[Id] = [c1].[ProjectId] AND CONTAINS([c1].[FullText], @__FullTextFilter_1)))
    ORDER BY [p].[ProjectName]
    OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [DropDowns] AS [d] ON [t].[ProjectStatusId] = [d].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[ProjectName]',N'@__FullTextFilter_1 nvarchar(4000),@__p_2 int,@__p_3 int',@__FullTextFilter_1=N'"*def*"',@__p_2=0,@__p_3=20
```

When I execute this SQL code, the execution time is about **460** ms (it's the same when I use the good old `SqlDataReader` with the generated sql query. I can't understand why the same query runs so slow in EF. I already tested:

- FullText column as computed column for fulltext index (like the code above)
- FullText column as normal string column (I copied all the text in this column, so the content was the same as the computed column)
- Fulltext index on the single columns (like SearchKeywords, ProjectName, ProjectDescription, ...)
- `EF.Functions.FreeText` instead of `EF.Functions.Contains`
- Disabled lazy loading via `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(false).UseSqlServer("xxx"));` (but in my test case there are no proxies in the data no matter if enabled or disabled)
- Waited some "warmup" time

Any ideas what is wrong here? I understand EF will add some overhead, but this is way too much.

Comment: Can you try this extension method [WithRecompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316)? To ensure that you do not have Parameter Sniffing problem.

Comment: Performance is why I dislike EF so much. Also, your columns are not of type string, that is not a datatype in sql server. They would be something like (n)varchar.

Comment: It's good that you're using the profiler, but honestly, when the queries are this complex, create a stored procedure/UDF/View instead and let SQL server do the heavy lifting. In that instance, EF is essentially a pass through and now you're just dealing with a SQL query performance issue and not an EF *and* SQL issue. Additionally here, the query profiler is your best friend in determining the cause of the slow down. The actual query plans are only semi-deterministic and the same SQL can generate different plans (and consequently different performance), at different times.

Comment: There's just too many OR clauses. That being said, since outermost select only selects from one table, may be try converting all join conditions to EXISTS

Comment: Does the query execution time change when you run it through your test or are you saying your total test execution time is slow? If you profile multiple runs where it swings from 500ms to 10000ms, does the query plan change?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you! Looks like Parameter Sniffing is the right way. Just tested it with a constant parameter, and the execution time is very close to the sql native execution time. I will do some more tests and come back here later.

Comment: @SeanLange The column type is indeed nvarchar(max). It was text before, but with text I had big trouble because the parameter was nvarchar.

Comment: @SalmanA I need all of them and the point is, it runs good in SQL.

Comment: @HasaniH No, 500ms was SQL native, in EF it was 9000-10000ms for one execution.

Comment: The problem is likely to be with the TeamId. If the data is always a guid you can change this to nvarchar(36) or even nvarchar(128) that way you will be telling sql it a good primary filter. You can then index that col it give sql some hope of eliminating all the other team data.

Comment: @KevinBosch TeamId is a foreign key to the team table, so it should be fine.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Sadly I can't tag you in the answer, but you were absolutely right, Parameter Sniffing was the key here (see my answer). Thank you so much!

Comment: The data type was `text`, seriously? Seems appropriate to mention that as of [SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql), _The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv While it works good the most of the time, I discovered a problem with a simple SELECT statement (similar like in my question, but without any CONTAINS). The query takes 100ms in SQL server, but when my app is running, it takes 25,000ms in SQL server. When I close the app, it's 100ms again. Seems like EF is blocking the sql server. After some tries, it takes 100ms even while the app is running. Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **SvyatoslavDanyliv** for pointing me in the right direction. **Parameter Sniffing** is the keyword here.

I tested the mentioned [RecompileExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316) which gave me a good result (about 600ms in most cases), but sometimes still about 2000ms instead of 500ms.

In my case disabling parameter sniffing for the whole database (for now) worked best:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = OFF;
```

Now all my FreeText EF queries run about 500ms, nearly 100% as fast as the native SQL query.