# LINQ Execution Timeout gets fixed by a Distinct() call

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

SO Community I turn to you for explanation since I cannot find one myself.

Consider having a LINQ preparation query that inner joins multiple tables (around 20) which I won't share the details of to keep the question description as short as possible. I'm using deferred execution so am not calling ToList() yet.

Next, out of that anonymous IQueryable, using LINQ, I pull filtered columns, which are needed for the specific part of the method. Like so:

```
var specificColumns =
                from c in preparationQuery
                select new
                {
                    c.Col1,
                    c.Col2,
                    c.Col3,
                    c.Col4,
                    c.Col5,
                    ....more columns
                };
```

Now, I needed more specific data for another type of query, so I do this:

```
var moreSpecificColumns = 
                from c in specificColumns
                where c.Col5 > 0
                select new
                {
                    c.Col1,
                    c.Col2,
                    c.Col3
                };
```

Up to this point everything executes in under a second since there's not much data to begin with.

This is where it gets interesting when I use the latter query like this:

```
                from c in moreSpecificColumns
                join cci in Db.Table1 on c.Col1 equals cci.Col1
                join ceo in Db.Table2 on cci.SomeId equals ceo.SomeId
                join cbmo in Db.Table3 on cci.SomeId equals cbmo.SomeId
                join cwo in Db.Table4 on cci.SomeId equals cwo.SomeId
                join cb in Db.Table5 on new
                {
                    cci.SomeId,
                    SomeColumnName = c.Col2,
                    cci.SomeId,
                    cci.SomeOtherId,
                    c.Col3
                } equals new
                {
                    cb.SomeColumnName,
                    cb.SomeId,
                    cb.SomeOtherId,
                    cb.AnotherId,
                    cb.AndAnotherId
                }
                join cbuo in Db.Table6 on cb.SomeId equals cbuo.SomeId
                join ceoLkv in Db.Table7 on new {KeyId = ceo.SomeId ?? 0, LCID = SomeId} equals new {ceoLkv.KeyId, ceoLkv.LCID}
                    into ceoLkvs
                from ceoLkv in ceoLkvs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join cbmoLkv in Db.Table7 on new {KeyId = cbmo.SomeId ?? 0, LCID = SomeId} equals new {cbmoLkv.KeyId, cbmoLkv.LCID}
                    into cbmoLkvs
                from cbmoLkv in cbmoLkvs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join cwoLkv in Db.Table7 on new {KeyId = cwo.SomeId ?? 0, LCID = SomeId} equals new {cwoLkv.KeyId, cwoLkv.LCID}
                    into cwoLkvs
                from cwoLkv in cwoLkvs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where cci.DeletedDate == null
                select new
                {
                    Col1 = ceoLkv != null ? ceoLkv.DisplayValue : ceo.Name,
                    Col2 = cbmoLkv != null ? cbmoLkv.DisplayValue : cbmo.Name,
                    Col3 = cwoLkv != null ? cwoLkv.DisplayValue : cwo.Name,
                    Col5 = cbuo.Name,
                    cci.Col6,
                    cci.Col7,
                    cci.Col8,
                    cci.Col9,
                    cci.Col10,
                    cci.Col11
                }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
```

This is the first time I call the .ToList() to enumerate the collection.

This works in 95% of the time BUT there are edge cases when LINQ/EFCore has issues and execution Times Out.

Debugging shows no issues in number of records, none of these tables have more than 3000 entries and the number of records retrieved per request is at most 1000, but usually around 150.

The execution times out at random and has no direct connection with the collection size. Debugger always stops at the last query and Times out there, when it times out.

The fix I've found is wrapping the second query: `moreSpecificColumns` in a `.Distinct()` call, it solves all the issues. This has no effect on the number of unique records, the number is the same with or without the Distinct in all the cases.

I've also translated the "final" linq query to T-SQL and the only difference is `DISTINCT` statement after `SELECT`, nothing else.

My question is why does `Distinct()` make a difference and fixes those edge cases when there's no actual difference in the data set retrieved?

Comment: LINQ isn't embedded SQL. It's used as a query language over an ORM, EF Core, whose job is to provide in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. If you have to write explicit JOINs something is *very* wrong. `inner joins multiple tables (around 20)` that would be a bad SQL query to begin with, much less a LINQ approximation of that query.

Comment: `none of these tables have more than 3000` and yet, 3000^20 is a pretty big number, especially if the wrong JOIN conditions are used or if there are no indexes. 3000*1000*150... is big too if no indexes are used. The fact `Distinct` removes the timeout probably means the query returns tons of duplicate rows that are eliminated by DISTINCT. The timeout is caused because the server has to calculate all those duplicates and return them over the wire.

Comment: In this case, I would've gathered the generated SQL code through SQL Profiler and analyzed that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos All the tables are indexed, the query executes in approximately 1.5s, not going to delve into reasons behind a big query.call to DISTINCT doesn't make any difference in the number of records retrieved.

Comment: Doesn't mean this is a good or even readable query or that the generated 20-join SQL, which is what's slow, would be fast. Check that query's execution plan to see why it's wrong but such a LINQ query is *certainly* wrong

Comment: Instead of translating the query you should [log the real one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) and inspect its execution plan in SSMS or Azure Data Studio. I suspect that quirky JOIN on `Table5` will generate some unexpected SQL. There's no multi-column equality in SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately it seems there's no better way to connect all the tables without restructuring the database itself which is a no-can-do type of work. So it makes more sense to work with what is available and all that data needs to be joined otherwise the data set is wrong.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let me get back to you with that log, I'll double check it, really curious to know if there's a better way of doing it without actually changing the DB.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Would still have to write joins even with EF Core since not all tables are related, yet I still require the data from them. So joins are unavoidable, unless, like I said, the tables relations are modified, which is not possible as I am not the owner of the DB. There's no denying that the query is wrong though, but don't see a better way of handling it without deeper refactoring

Comment: Entity relations have nothing to do with foreign key constraints. If you have a `Blog` class with a `Posts` collection, EF Core will create a relation between `Blog.Id` and `Post.BlogId` no matter what constraints are configured in the database, simply using naming conventions. The LINQ query `from blog in context.Blogs where blog.Author.Name="..." from post in blog.Posts select post.Title` will generate the proper joins automatically between the `Blogs`, `Authors` and `Posts` table. If the primary key columns are indexed, the query will be fast

Comment: It seems that, by a stroke of luck, `DISTINCT` forces the query into a more favorable query plan.

Comment: If you're working in LINQ-to-SQL and things are timing out, the **very first thing** you need to do is inspect the generated SQL. ORMs are not magic bullets, there is only so much they can do, and especially with very complex queries it's often best to just write the requisite SQL yourself.

Comment: Check your query for [Parameter Sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077746/10646316)